# Pages like on facebook

Tags: 7, users

Is it possible to create "pages" like on facebook where one user can switch through different "pages" (profiles in my case) and write separately on each one. (or upload images, galleries etc.).

Which modules to use, how to set them up ?

Better explanation:
Think of it as myspace website where each profile (band) has bio, gallery, videos, audio etc.
I have created content types for all mentioned groups of content and using views filters and menus to sort them out for individual users (bands), but i want to make role manager, so he can manage several bands.

So for example manager has bands A B C D E and uploads image gallery and somehow tells Drupal that uploaded gallery should go to band C. Same goes with videos, news etc.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do it ? Which modules to use ? How to set them up ?

Comment: Asking for "*which modules*" is NOT allowed as per the *Rules* of this site (which "I" did not invent ...). Therefor try to rephrase that to something like "which ways", or "which approaches/recipes" would you recommend. If your question would get enough votes to be reopened, don't be surprised to get answers like "*sure, there is a module for it, it is XYZ*" .... (which is perfectly acceptable as an answer, and quite often is what such answers are about) ... Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget this is Q+A - simple, small, narrowly scoped questions and equivalent answers. "Please give me instructions to build this site/feature from scratch" isn't appropriate here I'm afraid

Comment: This is question nb. 60 from me, so i know the rules. I can not understand where from my question you see me asking how to build entire website ? As i wrote the web is done, this is one extra feature. How would you ask it ? Would you be happy with answer from No Ssswear ? Do i need to link questions mile long with mile long answers ? Pierre, i can link 100 questions asking "which module". You guys are moderators, so do something to change the rules. How many modules are there for Drupal ? How many do the same exact thing ? How many tutorials and modules are just for facebook like ?

Comment: "which modules" has 13,268 results. Cheers.